# How to solve duplicate output by using search bar in ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

I am using ionic 4. I want to do search function in my apps. I am using search bar and get the result from API.

My problem is it always output duplicate result.

One problem is I haven't typing the word finish it already match the result that I want to search, then it will output the result.

Another problem is when I finish typing it output again the result.

How can I solved or avoid this problem?

Here is my html code:

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="name" (ionCancel)="onCancel($event)" (ionChange)="Search($event)"></ion-searchbar>
```

Here is my home.page.ts

```
Search() {
  this.myService.getSearch(this.name);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one sounds like you are not wiping the data in your `this.myService.getSearch` call - check what it does in there, is it starting from a new list or just returning more results? If that doesn't solve that issue then post the code for that section.

The first issue is by design.

You can slow this down with the `debounce` option:

```
<ion-searchbar debounce="1500"></ion-searchbar>
```

There are two input events you can experiment with `ionChange` and `ionInput` - they act differently but I cannot remember exactly which does which, you will have to try them both. A third option would be to handle neither of them and just use a submit button.

Comment: thank you for your reply, from here this.myService.getSearch is starting from a new list. I have try both this ionChange and ionInput, both of them look same. If it possible I want to use submit button in ion-searchbar?

Comment: how I using this <ion-searchbar debounce="1500"></ion-searchbar> Thank you

Comment: debounce means that after it does a search it will wait 1500ms (1.5s) before it sends the next request off, so it slows down the search from searching after every character, but doesn't completely stop it.